# Making SEF URLs with K2 v2.6.5

Tags: joomla, seo, joomla-k2, sef

I'm using Joomla 2.5.1 along with K2 2.6.5. I am trying to figure out how to use SEF urls in K2. I have my site with the 'real' folder 'coolmovies'. Joomla controls this folder.

Within K2, I have a category alias='scifi', within which I have an item alias='startrek' and 'startrek' has the item id 42. Currently this url works:

http://mycoolsite.com/coolmovies/42-startrek

I update the SEF settings for K2 to the following:
[image: SEF settings for K2 v2.6.5]

In theory, this should now work:

http://mycoolsite.com/coolmovies/scifi-startrek

But it doesn't. I've tried all kinds of permutations, but I get nothing but 404 errors.

I've found this link for reference.
http://getk2.org/community/New-to-K2-Ask-here-first/6472-K2-SEO-issue---Can-it-be-fixed?limit=20&start=40

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

from my experience, it is very difficult to control k2 url's using joomla core SEF. you will probably have to install a 3rd party component.

i eventually installed artioJoomSEF and managed to sort it out.

you can also try aceSEF (http://www.joomace.net/joomla-extensions/acesef-joomla-seo-sef-urls), which i find easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The construction of your URL is wrong. If your category alias is "scifi" and your article alias is "startrek" the url should be

http://mycoolsite.com/scifi/startrek