# URL SEO-friendly JOOMLA

Tags: url, joomla, friendly-url, joomla-k2, joomla-component

I'm using the K2 component for a site in joomla. When I click on an item created with K2 becomes the URL:
"my_domain/component/k2/title_article".
how do I do not see "/component/k2/"?
In the global settings of joomla "Enable SEF URLs" and "Rewrite SEF URLs" are enabled.
Thank you.

Comment: check this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767743/making-sef-urls-with-k2-v2-6-5

Comment: I installed the JoomSEF extension but does not remove the string "/component/k2/" from url.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you hace access to the server configuration? if it is an Apache server you could create a rule in an .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to know your Joomla version.

K2 has its own SEF engine that works great. Go to Extensions -> K2 -> Parameters -> Advanced and search for Enable advanced SEF on the page. Make sure the radio button is set to yes and see the result. This works with K2 2.6.4 and above.

---

Additionally to give a specific URL path to an article created with K2, you need to assign it to a menu item. You have to go to the menu manager and add a new menu that is a K2 item, then the item will take the url of the menu item.

This is not good if you have hundreds of articles, but for a few it works.